# Tizen Native Application Unable to create

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I am trying to create Tizen Native app, But i am unable to create app, View my below picture there is no samples available in native app, My Tizen sdk version is 2.1.1 [image]

Comment: What about the templates? It seems like it would make more sense to use one of the templates to start writing an app of your own.

Comment: @Michael Template and sample are missing that is my error,how i reactive it

Comment: @appubala, why are  you using an old version? Probably, you should first update to the latest stable (2.2.1) or to 2.3b?

Comment: @Michael It worked I uninstall & install it in different directory

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you how to do this using Tizen Native (WYSIWYG). If you are seeking a code based answer, then ignore this. HOWEVER, for those trying to learn and navigate within Tizen Studio this is very helpful!

Start Tizen Studio

File/New Tizen Project

Template / Next

Mobile / Next

Native Application / Next

UI Builder Single View (Bottom Left) / Next

In the Project Explorer (Top Left) open the tree to Layout / Layout.xml (Double click to open the Layout).

Choose Design Tab (Center)

In Palette , UI Container (just to right of center)

Drag "Grid" from the Palette onto your screen

In Properties Tab (far right or turn on: Window/ Show View/ Other/ choose properties OK)

Change Col Count to 720 and Row Count to 1280

Drag "Grid" from the Palette onto your screen

Now you should see more (22) UI Components

Drag "Background" from the Palette onto your screen If it does not automatically resize (Hello BUG) then do the following. Drag to a little LARGER then your screen size (assuming HD, Look into this I think this is REQUIRED by the Tizen Store).

With Background highlighted, again go to Properties Tab, bottom Variation Attributes make: Left 0, Top 0, Width 720, Height 1280. The first few times it will give you trouble until you figure out that the BG resized window can't go higher than the BLUE TOP and the window should be larger on the bottom, until you manually type in the CORRECT SIZE as shown above.

Now go to or open your Resource Tab (just drag and drop files here from Windows Explorer) and find your background image that you already RESIZED CORRECTLY in Adobe PS and used SAVE FOR WEB to reduce jpg file size.

Drag onto Background "layer" on your Screen.

For a button you can: Drag "BUTTON" from UI components onto Background OR BETTER is to drag "IMAGE" from UI components onto Background...

Then drag and drop (PRE-MADE BUTTON from Adobe PS) image from the Resource Manager Tab onto the empty image place holder. You will have to resize it manually in the Properties Tab to get the correct proportions.

REPEAT for more Images and Buttons and Text since the built in text "Label" is horrible to say the least. You can always make any of these do Button Actions.

This is as far as I have come, now I need to learn how to program said buttons and actions.

Whew! This will save you many weeks! Wish I had found a step by step like this!

Now where to post this? IO

P.S. If you find this useful. Tick the little black up arrow to up vote this. Purely to help others, I receive no reward for "likes".